# Is there a violation in the Onsager-Kelvin relation in Normal metal - superconductor junctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity, mesoscopic-physics

I'm currently reading the paper https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.48.15198

It is about charge $I$ and heat $I_H$ currents in NS junctions due to temperature $(\Delta T)$ and voltage $(V)$ biases. They are using the BTK formalism, where $R_{e,h}$ represents normal/Andreev reflection.

In appendix D the authors derive the relations
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&I = GV + L(\Delta T),\\
&I_H = G_H V + L_H(\Delta T).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The response functions are given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&G = \frac{2e^2}{h} \int (1-R_e+R_h)\left(- \frac{df}{dE}\right)dE\\
&L = \frac{2e}{hT} \int (1-R_e+R_h)(E-\mu)\left(- \frac{df}{dE}\right)dE\\
&G_H = \frac{2e}{h} \int (1-R_e-R_h)(E-\mu)\left(- \frac{df}{dE}\right)dE\\
&L_H = \frac{2}{hT} \int (1-R_e-R_h)(E-\mu)^2\left(- \frac{df}{dE}\right)dE\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Here $f$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution.

However, this seems to violate the Onsager reciprocity relations found for instance in these papers: 
https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.93.224509
https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.96.115404
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00339-007-4189-0.pdf.

It seems to me that the Onsager reciprocity relations state that $TL = G_H$, which is clearly not the case in the expressions above. Can someone explain this apparent discrepancy to me?

Comment: Is there anything I should add to make the question more accessible?

Comment: $L=G_H$ seems to be dimensionally inconsistent, right?

Comment: Yes, there is supposed to be a prefactor in the expressions which make them dimensionally consistent. However, the main issue is that to me these integrals seem completely different, due to the sign in front of the Andreev reflection. Nevertheless, there seems to be some consensus in the literature that these integrals are supposed to give the same number. Which to me only seems to be true if $R_h = 0$.

Comment: I never were able to figure this out, but I'm still interested in a possible resolution.